# how to execute objective-c code serially in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code, I am new to iOS. In the code I use `myData` (`NSMutableArray`) to pass data to table view. If `myData` is hardcoded, it is loading properly on table view. But whenever I try to assign data in the function otherBrandsInGivenSize(), I am not able to assign data to `myData` variable. NSLog prints properly in the sequence up to "hiiii","1","2","3". But after that it prints "sanket". Expected sequence should be "hiiii","1","2","3","4","helo" then "sanket". Can any one explain me Why?

```
#import "Result.h"
@interface Result ()
{
    NSMutableArray *myData; 
}

@end
@implementation Result
@synthesize  suggestedBraSizelaLabel;

@synthesize suggestedSize;
@synthesize brandName;
@synthesize bandSize;
@synthesize cupSize;
//@synthesize myData;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"hiiiiii");
        suggestedBraSizelaLabel.text = suggestedSize;

    [self otherBrandsInGivenSize];
    NSLog(@"sanket");
    NSLog(@"%@",myData[1]);
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)myData.count);

   // myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Data 1 in array",@"Data 2 in array",@"Data 3 in array", @"Data 4 in array",@"Data 5 in array",@"Data 5 in array", @"Data 6 in array",@"Data 7 in array",@"Data 8 in array", @"Data 9 in array", nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [myData count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *stringForCell;
    stringForCell =[myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.88375946969999997 green:0.03064271168 blue:0.42822685980000003 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.textLabel setText:stringForCell];
    return cell;

}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UILabel *headerTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    headerTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    headerTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.88375946969999997 green:0.03064271168 blue:0.42822685980000003 alpha:1.0];
    headerTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerTitle.text = @"Recommended size in other brands";
    return headerTitle;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(void)otherBrandsInGivenSize{
    NSLog(@"1");

    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.api.abc.com/v1/calculator/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

    //Specify method of request(Get or Post)
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //
    //Pass some default parameter(like content-type etc.)
    [theRequest setValue:@"someKEY" forHTTPHeaderField:@"API-Key"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSString *jsonPostData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ \"%@\" %@ \"%@\"%@",@"{", @"\"bandSize\":",bandSize ,@", \"cupSize\":",cupSize,@"}"];
   // NSLog(@"%@",jsonPostData);

    NSLog(@"2");
    // "brandName": "Enamor",
    //"sizeChartValue": "BandandCupSize"
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[jsonPostData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSLog(@"3");

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
         NSLog(@"4");           
         id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

         NSLog(@"helo");

         if ([jsonObject[@"status"]  isEqual: @"success"]) 
         {
             // NSLog(@"%@",[jsonObject objectForKey:@"data"]);
             NSArray * responseArray = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"data"];

             myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

             for ( NSDictionary *aDict in responseArray)
             {
                 //NSLog(@"%@", aDict[@"brand"]);
                 [myData addObject:[aDict valueForKey:@"brand"]];                                    
             }
             NSLog(@"%@",myData);
             [self.myTable reloadData];
        }
    }] resume];
}

- (IBAction)resetButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"resetSegue" sender:self];

    });
}
@end
```

Comment: Please write your `responseArray` so all have good idea.

Comment: should consider remove some irrelevant code before posting

Answer (score 0):

If you using cmd + F6 step, you'll find that the program did not enter inside the block and it return directly. Because the block is just a piece of code, it will never execute unless someone called.

Comment: it will enter in the program, I am calling this code from some other class.

Comment: so in the current method will not wait some other class call

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to asynchronous http request.